# Refusal of UK visitor's visa

Tags: uk

How can I explain to the UKVI about my insufficient financial position? I presented my bank statements, and they they refused to give me a 10-day visitor's visa.

I presented documents showing that my cousin is responsible for all my expenses and attached transfer slips of money sent by my cousin as evidence, but yet they refused my application, stating that I'm not financially sound to travel to the UK.

Comment: Don't write the title (or anything else) in all caps, that is considered as rude as shouting. Please upload your refusal (with personal details edited out) so we can see exactly why your visa was refused.

Comment: *inefficient*? Did you mean *insufficient*?

Answer (score 5):

Your cousin is not applying for the visa, you are. You need to show that you can support yourself on your own (without relying on your cousin) and have a compelling reason to leave the UK at the end of holiday - such as a job and/or a house (property) and/or a family.

Please see [this excellent guide](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/66104/should-i-submit-bank-statements-when-applying-for-a-uk-visa-what-do-they-say-ab/66105#66105) from Gayot Fow.

Comment: To be fair, Gayot's answer explicitly says sponsored applications are acceptable, but are much weaker and should only be used as a last resort. So the first line of your answer is not an entirely accurate summary.

Answer (score 0):

You may have been refused because your finances at home are low so they think you would want to work illegally in the UK.

I haven't seen the refusal letter so this is speculation at this point.